# Pylint Process spamming in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, ide, cpu-usage, pylint

I have some trouble while using pylint in vscode.

While writing some lines in vscode, I can watch my CPU usage is going up. A look at the process tree shows multiples pylint processes with the same arguments, the file which I modified.

Is this a normal behavior of pylint or could there be a bug or misconfiguration in vscode?

[image: python process spam]

My environment is as follows:

```
# vscode
Version: 1.78.2

# python venv environment

# pylint: python -m pylint --version
pylint 2.17.4
astroid 2.15.5
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 13 2023, 10:26:41) 
[GCC 9.4.0]
```